# How to implement logout in Azure AD application proxy

Tags: azure-active-directory, http-headers, single-sign-on, session-cookies, single-logout

I have integrated header based application with Azure AD application proxy.
Which preauthenticate user with Azure AD credential and created cookie based session.
How to implement logout so that when clicking logout link on application it totally clears the session.

Answer (score 1):

For OAuth/OIDC, provided the guidance:

"When you want to sign out the user from your app, it isn't sufficient to clear your app's cookies or otherwise end the user's session. You must also redirect the user to the Microsoft identity platform to sign out."

"When you redirect the user to the end_session_endpoint, the Microsoft identity platform clears the user's session from the browser.
However, the user may still be signed in to other applications that use Microsoft accounts for authentication."

Implement logout in Azure AD application proxy:

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-a-sign-out-request